# TWTRTimelineViewController with Guest Authentication

Tags: ios, authentication, twitter, ios9, twitter-oauth

I am encountering numerous issues while trying to use the TWTRTimelineViewController with Guest Authentication.

From following the documentation [here](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/authentication.html#guest-authentication), and following the tutorial [here](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/show-timelines.html), I should be able to show the TWTRTimelineViewController without issue, but I keep getting the following error code when initializing Fabric:

`[Fabric] failed to download settings Error Domain=FABNetworkError Code=-5 "(null)"`.

I've tried searching for this error and I cannot find anything related to the -5 error code.

I have also tried initializing Fabric using

`[[Twitter sharedInstance] startWithConsumerKey:kTwitterConsumerKey consumerSecret:kTwitterConsumerSecret];`

and

`[Fabric with:@[ [Twitter sharedInstance] ]];`

but doing that results in the same error displaying as well as the following error when trying to set the `dataSource` on the TWTRTimelineViewController:

`[TwitterKit] Couldn't load tweets from TWTRTimelineViewController: Error Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=200 "Request failed: forbidden (403)"`

Has anyone ever had this issue before or can anyone show me how to properly display a twitter feed using the TWTRTimelineViewController with Guest Authentication?

Thanks in advanced for all of the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.

Fabric was not being initialized properly which is what was causing the errors.

Once I got Fabric initialized, everything works as expected from the tutorials.